# Merging a list of dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary, merge

I have a list of dicts as below.

```
list = [ {id: 1, s_id:2, class: 'a', teacher: 'b'} ]
list1 = [ {id: 1, c_id:1, rank:2, area: 34}, {id:1, c_id:2, rank:1, area: 21} ]
```

I want to merge the two lists on the common key-value pairs (in this case 'id:1')

```
Merged_list = [ {id:1, s_id:2, class: 'a', teacher: 'b', list1: {c_id:1, rank: 2, area: 34}, {c_id:2, rank: 1, area: 21} ]
```

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Are the dicts always lined up like this so the first goes with the first in the other list, etc?

Comment: Yes, @Mark. The first key is always the same in both lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
merged_list = [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2)]

>>> merged_list
    [{'id': 1, 's_id': 2, 'class': 'a', 'teacher': 'b', 'rank': 2, 'area': 34},
     {'id': 2, 's_id': 3, 'class': 'c', 'teacher': 'd', 'rank': 1, 'area': 21}]
```

where `{**d1, **d2}` is just a neat way to combine 2 dictionaries. Keep in mind this will replace the duplicate keys of the first dictionary. If you're on Python 3.9, you could use `d1 | d2`.

**EDIT**: For the edit in your question, you can try this horrible one liner (keep in mind this will create the pair `list1: []` if no matching indeces were found on `list1`):

```
list_ = [{"id": 1, "s_id": 2, "class": 'a', "teacher": 'b'}]
list1 = [{"id": 1, "c_id": 1, "rank": 2, "area": 34}, {"id": 1, "c_id": 2, "rank": 1, "area": 21}]

merged_list = [{**d, **{"list1": [{k: v for k, v in d1.items() if k != "id"} for d1 in list1 if d1["id"] == d["id"]]}} for d in list_]

>>> merged_list
    [{'id': 1,
      's_id': 2,
      'class': 'a',
      'teacher': 'b',
      'list1': [{'c_id': 1, 'rank': 2, 'area': 34},
       {'c_id': 2, 'rank': 1, 'area': 21}]}]
```

This is equivalent to (with some added benefits):

```
merged_list = []
for d in list_:
    matched_ids = []
    for d1 in list1:
        if d["id"] == d1["id"]:
            d1.pop("id") # remove id from dictionary before appending
            matched_ids.append(d1)
            
    if matched_ids: # added benefit of not showing the 'list1' key if matched_ids is empty
        found = {"list1": matched_ids}
    else:
        found = {}
        
    merged_list.append({**d, **found})
```

Comment: list = [ {id: 1, s_id:2, class: 'a', teacher: 'b'} ]
list1 = [ {id: 1, c_id:1, rank:2, area: 34}, {id:1, c_id:2, rank:1, area: 21} ]

Merged_list = [ {id:1, s_id:2, class: 'a', teacher: 'b', list1: {c_id:1, rank: 2, area: 34}, {c_id:2, rank: 1, area: 21} ]  

To be very specific, This is the operation i need to perform.

Comment: You need to update your question then. That is not what is portrayed there at all.

Comment: I get a 
Key Error: 'id' 
I don't know this happens.

Comment: You're constructing your dictionaries wrong. For instance, use `"id"`, not `id`.

Comment: I have actually converted a dataframe to a dictionary using the df.to_dict() function. So I don't think wrong construction is an issue.

Comment: Include more of your code in your question and I'll check.

Comment: That's as much as I can give away.
d1.pop("id") --> this is what is causing the error

Comment: Try printing `list1[0].keys()` to see the actual keys of your dictionaries and the type. The idea of a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is that you create a runnable piece of code that illustrates your problem or what you want to achieve. Your example in your question does not run because you aren't using valid keys. This is what I've been trying to tell you. What I did answers your question regarding your example and that is what you need to apply to your specific use case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

And don't forget to put " " when declare string

```
list = [ {"id": 1, "s_id": 2  ," class": 'a', "teacher": 'b'}, {"id": 2, "s_id" : 3, "class" : 'c', "teacher": 'd'} ]
list1 = [ {"id": 1, "rank" :2, "area" : 34}, {"id" :2, "rank" :1, "area": 21} ]

list2 = list1 + list
print(list2)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. This just extends both lists, meaning `list2` would now have 4 dictionaries inside.